# Как повысить производительность выборки данных

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Разрабатываю веб-приложение на asp.net mvc "словарь терминов" (на данный момент около 27 тыс. терминов). У терминов есть наименование на русском, белорусском и английском языках. Поля могут быть пустыми (должно быть заполнено хотя бы одно).
На странице единовременно работать можно только с одним из 3-х языков.
Фильтрацию данных обеспечиваю следующим образом:
1. Язык;
2. Первая буква (алфавит формирую только из тех букв, которые встречаются хотя бы раз + "ВСЕ" - для получения всего списка);
3. Подстрока (с учетом языка и первой буквы).

[image: Элемент для фильтрации данных]

Возникают проблемы на этапе выборки всего списка без заданной буквы и подстроки (запрос выполняется раза в 3-4 медленнее). Вот код метода (стыдно показывать, но без этого никак)

```
    public List<Term> GetTermsList(Conditions conditions)
    {
        List<Term> termsList = new List<Term>();
        switch (conditions.langCode)
        {
            case LangCode.EN:
                termsList = Context.Term
                    .Where(term => term.NameEN != "" 
                        && (term.NameEN.Substring(0, 1) == "\"" 
                            ? term.NameEN.ToUpper().Substring(1).StartsWith(conditions.selectedLetter) 
                            : term.NameEN.ToUpper().StartsWith(conditions.selectedLetter)))
                    .ToList();
                if (conditions.searchTerm != "")
                {
                    termsList = termsList
                        .Where(term => term.NameEN.ToUpper().Contains(conditions.searchTerm.ToUpper()))
                        .ToList();
                }
                break;
            case LangCode.BY:
                termsList = Context.Term
                    .Where(term => term.NameBY != "" 
                        && (term.NameBY.Substring(0, 1) == "\"" 
                            ? term.NameBY.ToUpper().Substring(1).StartsWith(conditions.selectedLetter) 
                            : term.NameBY.ToUpper().StartsWith(conditions.selectedLetter)))
                    .ToList();
                if (conditions.searchTerm != "")
                {
                    termsList = termsList
                        .Where(term => term.NameBY.ToUpper().Contains(conditions.searchTerm.ToUpper()))
                        .ToList();
                }
                break;
            default:
                termsList = Context.Term
                    .Where(term => term.NameRU != "" 
                        && (term.NameRU.Substring(0, 1) == "\"" 
                            ? term.NameRU.ToUpper().Substring(1).StartsWith(conditions.selectedLetter) 
                            : term.NameRU.ToUpper().StartsWith(conditions.selectedLetter)))
                    .ToList();
                if (conditions.searchTerm != "")
                {
                    termsList = termsList
                        .Where(term => term.NameRU.ToUpper().Contains(conditions.searchTerm.ToUpper()))
                        .ToList();
                }
                break;
        }
        return termsList;
    }
```

Можно ли как-то всю эту ерунду оптимизировать? Доступ есть и к таблицам на SQL(думал, может стоит создать представления для каждого языка отдельно или структуру поменять/создать какие-то индексы), и к коду соответственно.
В придачу к этому все данные выводятся не по страницам, а в один скроллируемый список, что тоже замедляет работу. Поэтому хотелось бы оптимизировать с учетом того, что нужно будет реализовать виртуальный скроллинг(или нечто подобное).
Мне важны абсолютно любые советы для саморазвития, так что не стесняйтесь в выражениях, насколько это допустимо правилами сайта.

Comment: Может быть выборку всего списка отдельно обработать через if и сразу вернуть всю таблицу?

Comment: Из комментариев к коду, у вас повторяющийся код, это не очень хорошо. Хорошо бы придумать как убрать повторения.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин думал добавить представления для каждого языка со структурой ID, Name (и заодно убрать пустые поля и отсортировать по алфавиту). Тогда повторяющегося кода не будет, но будут 3 представления в базе c приблизительно такими селектами:  

**`SELECT Id, NameRU as Name
FROM Term where NameRU is not null and NameRU != '' order by replace(NameRU,'"','')`**  

 Вопрос в том, как это скажется на производительности

Comment: А зачем replace? в `order by`, может просто `order by NameRU`

Comment: Вы поняли мой первый комментарий?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин первым символом в наименовании могут быть кавычки. Например **"ЗЕЛЕНАЯ" ЭКОНОМИКА**. Тогда этот термин окажется в начале списка, а не на букве **З**. Проблема в том, что такой селект выполняется значительно медленнее. А вот что будет, если создать такое представление, не ясно.

Comment: Возможно стоит завести отдельное поля для термина без кавычек, так как эти замены дорого обходятся. И сделать индекс по этому полю, будет искать в разы быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш запрос работает медленно, так как не используются индексы, даже если вы пропишите текстовые поля индексовыми, то быстрый поиск в вашем решении не сработает, так как используются replace. Индекс будет быстро работать только в ситуации когда текст ищется не из середины строки, или с заменами, а только при совпадении с началом строки.

Заметим, что поиск по индексу работает за логарифмическое количество операций в случае со строками, или даже ещё быстрее, в случае использования busket search.

А поиск без индекса работает за n операций, где n количество записей.

То есть при поиске по индексу вы можете на порядки увеличить скорость выборки.

Задача сделать так что бы быстрый индексный поиск заработал, для этого я вижу 3 решения.

**Первое.**

Вам стоит для каждой записи завести дополнительные поля со значением без кавычек.

И по этому полю сделать индекс.

Это увеличит размер базы, но в разы ускорит поиск.

Так как:

- Теперь у вас будет рабочий индекс
- Не будет replace-ов.

**Второе**

Делаем дополнительное булевское поле для записей которые начинаются с кавычкой (для каждого языка). В самом поле термина храним значение без начальной кавычки, но при выводе пользователю при `true` в этом спец. поле добавляем начальную кавычку.

И опять индекс на текстовые поля.

**Третий вариант**

Поиск делать в два этапа

1. Ищем `слово`
2. Ищем `"слово`

Результат объединяем.

Опять же индекс по текстовому полю.

Comment: Тогда replace нужно будет использовать для поискового запроса, чтобы убрать кавычки. Это конечно менее затратно с точки зрения производительности, но есть вероятность, что **"name"** и **name** в поисковой строке должны вернуть разные результаты. Я обдумаю, насколько этот нюанс значим. Спасибо за идею.

Comment: @viperishko replace вообще не нужен будет. Я добавил второй вариант решения.

Comment: @viperishko и добавил третий вариант, он думаю самый быстрый и простой.